# Get one element from an array of objects that's part of one document (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema which contains `Friends` . Friends is an array where each element is an object that contains an id, gender, and emoji.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    gender: String,

    Friends: [{
        id: String
        gender: String
        emoji: String

    }]

});
```

In the code below, I'm accessing one document which contains a Friends array and specifying that search with `distinct` such it only shows the document's array of Friends. I need to access only one element of that array that contains a specified id. Instead of filtering that array after the query like what's done in the code, is there a way to just get the element purely from the query? In other words, is there an extra functionality to distinct or some kind of mongoose operator that allows that?

```
User.findOne().distinct('Friends', { id: req.body.myId }).then(function(myDoc) {

    var friendAtt = myDoc.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id == req.body.id
    })[0]

})
```

Comment: Ever heard of the MongoDB Aggregation Framework??

Comment: never my friend, any hints before I go off researching it?

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to bertrand I was able to find that the answer lies in '`Projection`'. In mongodb it's '`$`', in mongoose its `select`. Here is how I made it work:

```
User.findOne({id: req.body.myId}).select({ Friends: {$elemMatch: {id: req.body.id}}}),
```

It only returns the element that matched the id specified in friends.

Comment: this gives back an array, but only elements that match your $elemMatch, (in my case, since ids are unique, one element)

Comment: You saved me, omg I was searching for that too lang.

Answer (score 10):

You don't really need `distinct` here, you can use `find()` on `Friends.id` and filter the first subdocument that match `Friends.id` with [the positional parameter `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/positional/) :

```
db.user.find(
    { 'id': 'id1', 'Friends.id': 'id2'},
    { 'Friends.$': 1 }
)
```

In mongoose :

```
User.find({ 'id': req.body.myId, 'Friends.id': req.body.id }, { 'Friends.$': 1 }).then(function(myDoc) {
    console.log("_id   :" + myDoc[0].Friends[0].id);
    console.log("gender:" + myDoc[0].Friends[0].gender);
})
```

Comment: the 'Friends.$' : 1' part

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/positional/. There is no example in mongoose doc for this I think

Comment: This doesn't really compile in mongoose Bertrand. The 'Friends.$' : 1' part. However that does give me an idea of where to look!

Comment: Here is a test  : https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/a3a90fed2a6b6cbd624bad9e7c7e8fd2